# Android Dialog- Keyboard behaviour for EditTexts

Tags: android, dialog, android-edittext, user-input, keyboard-layout

I have a dialog that asks the user to input a name, but the keyboard starts with the numbers characters instead than the letters as usual.

Here is the code I used:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Insert Name");
        final EditText nome = new EditText(this);
        final String NOME_TEXT = "Nome";
        nome.setHint(NOME_TEXT);
        nome.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PERSON_NAME);

        nome.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890 "));

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(nome);
        builder.setView(layout);
```

I'm sure that the annoying behaviour is caused by `nome.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("...")` that somehow changes the type of input keyboard, but I have to kekep the DigitsKeyListener and can't remove it because I want the user to be able to insert just alphanumeric chars, and for what I saw TextKeyListener or other listeners don't have the method to control what user is typing dynamically. Is it possible to show the keyboard I want?

Comment: You commented that you are "sure" that it has to do with `setKeyListener()`. Have you tested your code without this line and got the keyboard you were expecting?

Comment: Yes, without the setKeyListener the normal keyboard comes out but I'm able to put whichever char I want in the editText

Comment: Odd behavior! I have duplicated your results.   Swapping the order of `setInputType()` and `setKeyListener()` oddly allows you to see the standard keyboard, but the constraints on the acceptable character set are ignored.

Comment: I tried to search for some alternative methods to reach the solution, but they're so complex that I don't know if it'd be worth it.. I hope someone answers me with something! :)